# android :How to redirect on another activity in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

String [] name={ "Androidwarriors","Stackoverflow","Developer Android","AndroidHive","Slidenerd","TheNewBoston","Truiton","HmkCode","JavaTpoint","Javapeper"};
Context context;  LayoutInflater inflater;
public Recy
clerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

    RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
}

View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RecyclerViewHolder vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder) v.getTag();
        int position = vholder.getPosition();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, priya.class);
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below code
Instead of this pass context.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter { 
String [] name={"Androidwarriors","Stackoverflow","Developer Android","AndroidHive","Slidenerd","TheNewBoston","Truiton","HmkCode","JavaTpoint","Javapeper"};
Context context; 
LayoutInflater inflater; 
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context) 
{ 
  this.context=context; 
  inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context); 
}

@Override public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

   View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

   RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder=new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
   return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
holder.imageView.setTag(holder);
}

View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    RecyclerViewHolder vholder = (RecyclerViewHolder) v.getTag();
    int position = vholder.getPosition();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, priya.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
   }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, priya.class);
```

to

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, priya.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

To open new activity
Try this in your click listener

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
context.startActivity(mIntent);
```

Context you can get from First Activity or in adapter itself v.getContext().

Answer (score 1):

You can call activity from RecyclerAdapter like below:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, priya.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: final Intent intent = new Intent(context, priya.class);
context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: but it is static