# how to start activity using context.startActivity(intent);...?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclick, android-context

**my app crashes when i click and an error log appears directing to the line mentioned below and it is also shows that you have to declare RecyclerAdapterNew into manifest file but no need bcz i haven't extended to AppCompat**

```
public void onClick(View view) {


        tableData = Integer.parseInt(table.getText().toString());

        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecyclerAdapterNew.class);

        intent.putExtra("transfer", tableData);

        context.startActivity(intent);//error in this line
    }
```

Comment: Post your RecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: Post error log.

Comment: Cant call a simple class like that

Comment: RecyclerAdapterNew.class must be extending activity and it should be declared in manifest.xml file

Comment: check this link please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114409/android-how-to-redirect-on-another-activity-in-recyclerview/42114574#42114574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```java
((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with these lines?

`Context context = view.getContext();
context. startActivity`

try:

1) `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` inside the creation of the new intent

2) remove this: `Context context = view.getContext()`

3) change `context.startActivity` to `this` or `getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

if your not extend the RecyclerAdapterNew.class with Activity or not mentioned in `Manifest` file it wont work